# Navigator and inspector behaviors on Xcode with BigSur

Tags: ios, xcode, developer-tools, xcode12, macos-big-sur

Example on Xcode with OSX10.15 of before:
Tab1: Navigator opened and inspector closed
Tab2: Navigator closed and inspector opened

But after upgrade to BigSur, navigator and inspector can't have different open/close status in different tabs, do everyone facing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This observation is easy to confirm (though whether the change is due to Big Sur or to Xcode 12 is a bit unclear).

- You can show the Project Navigator in one window tab and the Debug Navigator in another window tab, but you cannot show the Project Navigator in one window tab and *no* Navigator in another window tab.
- Moreover (you didn't mention this), in the second window tab you cannot widen and narrow the Navigator pane. It shows at just one width and it either shows or it does not. (Xcode 12.4 may have fixed this part.)

An easy workaround is to use two windows on the same project (File > New > Window) rather than two window tabs within the same window (File > New > Window Tab).

But it might be worth filing a bug with Apple, as this is definitely a major change in behavior. It certainly feels buggy to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply matt.
That's a good suggestion to use two windows instead of window tabs.
I think thats's inconvenient for me since that works before.

Comment: I agree. I’ve reported this to Apple as a bug; that’s all one can do

Comment: @matt Would you mind posting the link to the filed bug? Thx

Comment: @antfarm there is no such thing as a link to a filed Cocoa bug. It goes into a black hole. Btw Apple claims to have fixed the bug.